# PHP $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] is not available, why?

Tags: php

There is various resources on this topic, but I am still unsure why is $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] unavailable, on both of my machines, on one is PHP running as PHP-DSO and on another is running as PH FascCGI with suEXEC.

I am dumping $_SERVER variables, have turned on RewriteEngine in script directory .htaccess but I still can't see this variable. Of course, official documentation ie empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428981/serverscript-url-when-is-it-reliably-present    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717874/serverscript-uri-not-working-alternative